# Toggle Rxjs stream from other observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm working on a video player with two distinguishing ways to tell whether an observable should be subscribed to or not. they are _videoInfo$ and _exit$. They are streams that emit values when invoked on the player.

I have an observable called _data$, which emits all the values I need to track, but I only want to subscribe to it when the video player is playing.

I know that the following approach is incorrect, but it explains what I am trying to achieve. It currently does not work, because I can't unsubscribe from _data$.

```
 const _data$ = data$.subscribe(event => {
  // data I need when video is playing
});

_videoInfo$.subscribe((res): void => {
  // when res emits it means a new video is starting
  _data$.subscribe();
});

_exit$.subscribe({
 next: () => {
  _data.unsubscribe(); // this does not work, but i want to unsubscribe here
 },
 error: () => {},
 complete: () => {}
});
```

How can I subscribe to _data$ when $videoInfo emits a value and unsubscribe from it when _exit$ emits a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`observable.subscribe()` returns a `Subscription` object which you can use to unsubscribe.

```js
let subscription;

_videoInfo$.subscribe((res): void => {
  // when res emits it means a new video is starting
  subscription = _data$.subscribe();
});

_exit$.subscribe({
 next: () => {
  if (subscription) {
   subscription.unsubscribe(); 
  }
 },
 error: () => {},
 complete: () => {}
});
```

Comment: Thank you, such a simple approach that I just completely missed.

Answer (score 1):

The operator way:

```
_data$.pipe(skipUntil($videoInfo),takeUntil(_exit$)).subscribe()
```